# Reuse project code for multiple apps

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, app-store

I have a project in Xamarin.iOS and I want to build it for different clients under different app ids with unique icons for each client. What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

There are many (many...) ways you could do this.

An easy one would be to create several application projects (.csproj) under the same solution (.sln).

Each project would have it's own configuration, defines, targets, even files (like icons). All sources would be **links** (i.e. file linking) from the *master* project.

That would allow you to customize/brand, build and publish each application separately, while maintaining a single code base across all of them (from a single solution).

Comment: Is there a tutorial for doing this?

Comment: Good starting point would be to search "Separation of concerns" and start from there. This would help in putting code into reusable libraries (or "components"). Dear child has many names and one other search term would be "Modular design".